# Ruby: add a simple function to Mylist < Array

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I'm struggling with some database migration stuff, and this is what I want to do:

I created a `Class Mylist < Array` with a method `each_hash` added, this method needs to act just like the Array's each, that means the two calls are equal:

```
list = Mylist.new

list.each |d|
  ...
end

list.each_hash |d|
  ...
end
```

I have tried here and there but it does not work, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want the `each_hash` to be the exact same thing as `each`, you could do `alias :each_hash :each`. It would make a call to `each_hash` to actually be a call to `each`. Would that be an option in your case?

Comment: Could you show what you tried? (i.e., show the code for your `Mylist` class)

Comment: @mbratch I have tried to return self.each in Mylist's each_hash function, but not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Charles Caldwell, works excellent
If you want the each_hash to be the exact same thing as each, you could do alias :each_hash :each. It would make a call to each_hash to actually be a call to each. Would that be an option in your case? – Charles Caldwell